# spring mvc and checkbox handling for map property

Tags: spring-mvc, checkbox

I have the following (note that I am using the spring [convention](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) by prefixing with underscore):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="speakersIds[${speaker.id}]"  value="true"  />
<input type="hidden"   name="_speakersIds[${speaker.id}]" value="false" />
```

speakersIds is a map property of my model.

```
Map<Long, Boolean> speakersIds;
```

The problem is that in my controller, unchecked checkbox are not set to false.

Example:

*if speakersIds[0] was checked, then speakersIds.get(0) == true*

*if speakersIds[0] was not checked, then  speakersIds.get(0) == null. <--- shouldn't this be == false?*

Why?

Comment: what happens if you change Boolean to boolean?

Comment: You cannot declare a map with boolean instead of Boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of map, the underscore convention do not seem to work.

I finally just used the same property name in the hidden input.

```
<input type="checkbox" name='speakersIds["${speaker.id}"]'  value="True" />
<input type="hidden"   name='speakersIds["${speaker.id}"]'  value="False" />
```

While testing I had to change the type of speakersIds from Map<Long, Boolean> to Map<String, Boolean> but it should work with long as map key too.